# numpy Typerror for np.sin(myArray)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Not sure why `print(np.sin(myArray))` is throwing an error whereas
`np.sin(np.array([1,2,3])))` is working fine. Here is my Code:

```py
import numpy as np
myArray = np.array(['1', '2', '3'])
print(myArray)                       # ['1' '2' '3']
print(np.sin(myArray))               # THIS LINE GIVES AN ERROR
print(np.sin(np.array([1, 2, 3])))   # [0.84147098 0.90929743 0.14112001]
print(np.sin([1, 2, 3]))             # [0.84147098 0.90929743 0.14112001]
```

Comment: Because those are strings, not integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

myArray = np.array(['1', '2', '3']) need to be changed to myArray = np.array([1, 2, 3])